# Use a class name to call variable of the same name

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a list of divs with the class "dot" as well as a a different class on each for a town name, (eg. london, glasgow etc.)

I'm trying to use the second class name as a variable in a function. If I echo the second class name into the function it reads it as just a string as opposed to the variable which represents a number...

```
var resize = function () {
    $('.dot').each(function () {
        uniName = $(this).attr('class').split(' ')[1];
        uniNameMargin = uniName / 2 - uniName;
        $('.' + uniName).animate({
            width: uniName,
            height: uniName,
            marginLeft: uniNameMargin,
            marginBottom: uniNameMargin
        }, 300);
    });
```

Currently this formula is trying to use the words as a number and returning a lot of NaNs as opposed to the number

Is there any way of making it read it as the related variable instead?

Thanks

Comment: Try wrapping up the variable in a `String()`?

Comment: you should use `parseInt(val, 10)`

Comment: Just add `+` to convert to integer like: `uniNameMargin = +uniName/2 - uniName;`

Comment: you have something like this: `<div class="dot london"></div>` so after `uniName = $(this).attr('class').split(' ')[1];` uniName=="london" ?

Comment: @DanielA.White, @Mr_Green — if you read the question properly, you’ll notice that `uniName`’s value will be something like `"london"` or `"glasgow"`. Does `+"glasgow"` or `parseInt("london", 10)` give you a number?

Comment: @PaulD.Waite yeah missed that point. TBH, I got diverted by daniel's comment. :|

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don’t show us where these variables are defined, but I assume they’re global variables. If so, they’re also properties of the global object, which in web browsers is the `window` property.

If you have an object’s property name as a string, you can access that property using square bracket notation:

```
var my_object;
my_object.london = 1;

var property_name = "london";
console.log( my_object[property_name] ); // Will log 1 to the console
```

So, you can access the value of your variables like this (as I said, assuming they’re global variables):

```
    uniName = $(this).attr('class').split(' ')[1]; // After this line, I’m assuming uniName has a value like "london"
    var uniNumber = window[uniName];
    uniNameMargin = uniNumber / 2 - uniNumber; // Here, we use [] notation to access the "london" property of the window object. If you have a global variable called "london" with a numerical value, this should now work.
```

---

I also notice that the variables in your `$('.dot').each` function aren’t declared within the function using `var`. If those variables have already been declared in a higher scope, cool, but if they’re only used in that function, you should declare them in that function using the `var` keyword, so that you don’t pollute the parent or global scope with variables you don’t need:

```
$('.dot').each(function () {
    var uniName = $(this).attr('class').split(' ')[1];

    var uniNumber = window[uniName];

    var uniNameMargin = uniNumber / 2 - uniNumber;

    $('.' + uniName).animate({
        width: uniName,
        height: uniName,
        marginLeft: uniNameMargin,
        marginBottom: uniNameMargin
    }, 300);
});
```

Comment: @bboybeatle: you’re most welcome — your question explained a difficult-to-describe issue well.